# User login always display "Invalid password" error in MEAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to write a simple user login method in node.js using mongoose and mongoDB as database. Everytime I register a new user, I am able to login with those credentials for a few times, but then somehow it starts displaying the error "Invalid password". Any help would be appreciated. Below are the code snippets:

HTML file:

```html
<form>
    <p>Email: <input type="email" ng-model="LC.logInfo.email" required></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" ng-model="LC.logInfo.password" required></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="LC.login()" class="logreg_button">
</form>
```

user.js (model file)

```
UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(enteredPassword){
return bcrypt.compareSync(enteredPassword, this.password)
    }

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
var user = this
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});
})
```

users.js (server side controller file)

```
login: function(req,res){
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            res.json({status: false, errors:err});
        }
        else if(user){
            if(user.validPassword(req.body.password)){
                req.session['userInfo'] = {
                id: user._id,
                first_name: user.first_name
                }
                res.json({status:true, userInfo: req.session['userInfo'] })
            } else {
                res.json({status: false, errors: 'Invalid password!'})
            }
        } else {
            res.json({status: false, errors: 'User not found!'})
        }
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to `login` service.

You generate hashed password in `pre save` hook. For first time this is correct but when an user need to be updated this hook corrupts the password.

You need to handle it in other ways. For example in `pre save` hook you would check if the user is new or not and if it's new then hash the password.